# Using GSocketClient, how do I read incoming data without knowing how many incoming bytes there will be?

Tags: gtk, glibc, gio

I am still struggling to be able to read incoming response messages from a piece of hardware my program is communicating with.

I am using a GSocketClient and am able to connect and successfully send messages using g_output_stream_write(). I then want to read the response sent back from the device, but I have no way of knowing how many bytes the reply will be in order to use g_input_stream_read(). I have also tried using g_input_stream_read_all(), but this seems to block the application and never return. I don't know how g_input_stream_read_all() determines that it has reached the end of a stream, but I assume the problem is somewhere there?

I know that there is incoming data because I can use g_input_stream_read() with a made-up byte size like 5 and I then see the first 5 incoming bytes, but the response size will always be different.

So my questions is, is there a way to determine how much data is waiting to be read so that I can plug that into g_input_stream_read() as a variable for the size to read? And if not, what is the correct usage of g_input_stream_read_all() to get it to not block like I am seeing it do?

Answer (score 0):

Does something like the following work?

```
#define BUF_SIZE 1024
guint8 buffer[BUF_SIZE];
GByteArray *array = g_byte_array_new();
gsize bytes_read;
GError *error = NULL;

while (g_input_stream_read_all(istream, buffer, BUF_SIZE, &bytes_read, NULL, &error))
{
    g_byte_array_append(array, buffer, bytes_read);
    if (bytes_read < BUF_SIZE)
        /* We've reached the end of the stream */
        break;
}
if (error)
    // error handling code
```

Comment: Hmm...I'll give it a shot tonight.